# Вывести описание и ярлык и название значений, конкретного атрибута

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу найти как вывести следующие параметры
Есть вот такой атрибут [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно вывести все значения этого атрибута, но не только их название, а так же ярлык и описание
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Как это можно сделать? Я вывожу только сами значения с помощью

```
echo wc_get_product(get_the_ID())->get_attribute('pa_ral');
```

Пытался найти в базе эти параметры, но там нашел только это в wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

Заранее спасибо за помощь!
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/muUc3.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wmUd.png

Answer (score 0):

Значит плохо искал)
В итоге не туда смотрел, помог поиск по БД
Вывел так

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy'      => [ 'post_tag', 'pa_ral' ], // название таксономии с WP 4.5
    'orderby'       => 'id',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'object_ids'    => null,
    'include'       => array(),
    'exclude'       => array(),
    'exclude_tree'  => array(),
    'number'        => '',
    'fields'        => 'all',
    'count'         => false,
    'slug'          => '',
    'parent'         => '',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'child_of'      => 0,
    'get'           => '', // ставим all чтобы получить все термины
    'name__like'    => '',
    'pad_counts'    => false,
    'offset'        => '',
    'search'        => '',
    'cache_domain'  => 'core',
    'name'          => '',    // str/arr поле name для получения термина по нему. C 4.2.
    'childless'     => false, // true не получит (пропустит) термины у которых есть дочерние термины. C 4.2.
    'update_term_meta_cache' => true, // подгружать метаданные в кэш
    'meta_query'    => '',
];

$terms = get_terms( $args );

foreach( $terms as $term ){
    print_r( $term->name );
    print_r( $term->description );
}
```